# Yii2 CRUD url issue

Tags: php, yii2

My Yii2 app is based on advanced template. I created CRUD for a model named News in backend side.

Now when I try to open

/localhost/backend/web/index.php?r=News

getting Unable to resolve the request News.

```
Not Found (#404)

Unable to resolve the request "News".
```

here is the structure:

```
backend

 models
   News

 controllers
   NewsController

 Views
   News
     index
     _form
     _search
     create
     update
     view
```

the url /localhost/backend/web/index.php?r=News

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your config main.php as well as controller here

Answer (score 1):

Try /localhost/backend/web/index.php?r=news it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

As Mihai P said the problem is probably because of the case sensitive, but if you for some reason need of the uppercase letter, you can just change you config/main.php file like that:

```
'components' => [
        'urlManager'=>[
            'rules'=>[
                'News'=>'/news',
            ],
            'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
        ],
        ...
```

Then you url will loo like /backend/web/index.php/News, if you want to remove the index.php take a look on that [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/) that give you some ways to do that.